# Angular ui carousel and directive scope issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created a simple [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nevIxuxxNpfb8SalgTx2?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue.

I have a directive with an isolated scope which updates every one second to increment a local timer.  I was expecting the isolated scope to not affect anything else.

In the Plunker example I can see the parents scope value isn't being updated but every one second the carousel is being 'refreshed'.  Apologies if this isn't the correct angular term but I'm still learning.

This is my directive code:

```
app.directive('timer', ['$interval', function ($interval) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var timeoutId;

        element.on('$destroy', function () {
            $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
        });

        // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
        timeoutId = $interval(function () {
            scope.seconds++;
        }, 1000);
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        scope: {
            seconds: '@'
        },
        template: '<div>Isolated: {{seconds}}</div>'

    };
}]);
```

How do I ensure the timer doesn't cause a refresh of the carousel?

Comment: In what way is the carousel refreshing?  When I run the plunker, everything looks normal to me.

Comment: The hurro() function is benig called every second and the called is being incremented and shown below the carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got to the bottom of this.  The issue wasn't the carousel but the $interval timer which was causing a $rootScope.$apply().

The $interval signature is function interval(fn, delay, count, invokeApply) so passing invokeApply as false prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

a few things don't look right in your Plunker.

1. binding a function like this is a bad idea. 
   `<p>{{hurro()}}</p>`
2. I don't use a directive to make a timer. $interval already does timing for you.  You can modify you js script like this. 
   remove the timer directive completely, add $interval to your controller, and call hurro from the Repeat function I added.
   You will see hurro() gets called independently of the Carousel refresh.

   ```
   function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope, $interval) {
     $scope.myInterval = 0;
     $scope.called=0;
     $scope.called2=0;
     $scope.mySeconds=10;
     var slides = $scope.slides = [];
     $scope.addSlide = function() {
       var newWidth = 600 + slides.length;
       slides.push({
         image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
         text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
           ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
       });
     };
     for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
       $scope.addSlide();
     }
   ```

   $scope.hurro = function() {
       $scope.called = $scope.called+1;
       $("#called").html($scope.called);
     }

   ```
         var refresh;
       $scope.Repeat = function () {
           refresh = $interval(function () {
               console.log("refresh at " + new Date().toString());
               $scope.hurro();
           }, 1000);
       }
       $scope.Repeat();
   ```

   }

Comment: 1. The function was to highlight the issue 2.The timer directive is a very cut down version to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing issue 2, but I was able to duplicate it easily. The counter went up about 10 times a second.  My guess is either you made a recursive loop accidentally, or Angular is watching for scope changes and/or web events many times a second.